# How to remove a certain class from all divs?

Tags: jquery

It took days and days trying to fix something but do not know how.
In my index.html page I have many divs with a class called "input".
I need to remove this class of all divs when the browser window is less than 960 pixels. Here is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $("div").removeClass("input");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're wanting to remove the "input" class to change the page's styling, you'd likely be better off adjusting how "input" makes the page look using CSS media queries.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered css media queries in stead?

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .input {
    // counter the styling from your default styles
  }
}
```

A few advantages to js:

- users with js diabled will see it as well
- no need to register the 'expensive' resize listener
- when you upscale you do not need to add the `input` class again, cause you never removed it (and how would you know where to add it in the first place)

I always try to go for a css solution first, and in this case it definitely seems the right thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for a width *greater than* 960.

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {  // switched '>' to '<'
        $("div.input").removeClass("input");
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that once the width drops below 960, increasing the window size back above 960 won't add back the input class.

Comment: I would also consider unbinding the resize event after condition is met.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-events.htm